# XOR for Object Identitification

Tags: c#, algorithm, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, monocross

In the code below, I was wondering why XOR (^) is being used to combine the hascodes of the constituent members of the composition (this is source from  MonoCross 1.3)?

1. Is the bitwise XOR of an `MXViewPerspective` object's `Perspective` and `ModelType` member's used to uniquely identify the instance ?
2. If so, is there a name for this property of the XOR operation (how XOR-ing two values (ie, hashcodes) guarantees uniqueness) ?

---

```
public class MXViewPerspective : IComparable
{
    public MXViewPerspective(Type modelType, string perspective)
    {
        this.Perspective = perspective;
        this.ModelType = modelType;
    }
    public string Perspective { get; set; }
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        MXViewPerspective p =(MXViewPerspective)obj;
        return this.GetHashCode() == p.GetHashCode() ? 0 : -1;
    }
    public static bool operator ==(MXViewPerspective a, MXViewPerspective b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) == 0;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(MXViewPerspective a, MXViewPerspective b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) != 0;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this == (MXViewPerspective)obj;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ModelType.GetHashCode() ^ this.Perspective.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Model \"{0}\" with perspective  \"{1}\"", ModelType, Perspective);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xor'ing hashcodes doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but is usually used to improve the distribution over a table without complicating the hashing.

You want to make 2 different values map to different hash keys if they differ in any of the fields (i.e. - same `ModelType`, but different `Perspective`, or vice versa). So you need to incorporate both values into your hash key. You could have used `+` for example, or shift and concatenate them (the latter would be better in fact, as it **would** guarantee uniqueness, but also extend the key length which might complicate hashing).

xor won't guarantee this uniqueness since if you flip the same bit in `ModelType` and `Perspective`, you'd get the same hash key, for example 5 ^ 7 = 1 ^ 3 = 2, but it's usually good enough. Eventually it all depends on the ranges and distributions of the values you provide.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! ... What is that in your profile pic, its kinda scary !?

Comment: Changed it 5 seconds ago :) - http://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/animals/photos/13-of-the-ugliest-animals-on-the-planet/blobfish